# Sympy incorrect substitution with subs

Tags: python, sympy, evaluation

```
q1 = Function('q1')(t)
f=cos(q1).diff(t)
f.subs(q1,pi/2)
```

I have a `function f = -sin(q1)*q1'` and I would like to evaluate it at when `q1=pi/2`. I would expect to get an answer: -(q1)' but instead I get: -0.
So not only the parameter q1 gets substituted but also its time derivative becomes zero, because q1 is now a constant.
Am I using a wrong method here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the given example, Sympy's substitution is giving the correct answer because we are trying to substitute `q1(t) = pi/2`, a constant function. So it's derivative is bound to be `0`. The answer `-Derivative(q1(t),t)` is correct only when `q1` and `q1'` are independent of each other, like in calculus of variations. In that case, it is better to use two different variables -- one for the `q1` and another for `q1'`. So, if we already know the function `f` it is better to define it directly rather than trying to derive it like

```
p, q, t = symbols('p, q, t')
f = -sin(p)*q    
f.subs( p, pi/2)
```

This should be the correct way to substitute if `q1` and `q1'` are independent of each other.

Comment: So I found out that I can substitute the `q1'` in the first place and then substitute the `q1`. I cannot define the function directly, because its is derived by sympy and it is a messy stuff.

Comment: Yes. For calculus of variations type calculation this approach works better.